# Index of the intersection of two normal subgroups of index a power of a prime p

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

H and K are normal subgroups of G. They both have finite index equal to a power of a given 
prime p. The intersection is a normal subgroup of finite index equal to a power of p. 
I can show finiteness. How do you show the index is a power of p ?

Comment: what have u tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $G / H \cap K$ embeds into $G/H \times G/K$.

Comment: For a different solution, you could also apply $HK/K \cong H / H \cap K$.

Comment: Thanks, this is quick and symmetrical.

Answer (score 3):

Let $N_1$ and $N_2$ be two subgroups such that $[G:N_1]=p^{n_{{1}}}$ and $[G:N_2]=p^{n_2}$ where $p$ is a prime number and $n_1,n_2\in \mathbb N$. We have $$[G:N_1\cap N_2]=[G:N_1][N_1:N_1\cap N_2]$$

Since $\frac{N_1N_2}{N_2} \cong \frac{N_1}{ N_1 \cap N_2}$, $[N_1:N_1\cap N_2]=[N_1N_2:N2]$. Note that $\frac{N_1N_2}{N_2}\leq\frac{G}{N_2}$ and so there is $n_3\in \mathbb N$ such that $[N_1N_2:N2]=p^{n_3}$. Thus, $[G:N_1\cap N_2]=p^{n_1+n_3}$.

Comment: Thanks, this is also an accepted answer as far as I am concerned.